# The Data.gov organization_list CKAN API is not working

Tags: data.gov, ckan

[This file](http://catalog.data.gov/api/3/action/organization_list) is supposed to be giving the JSON format of all the organizations present in [Data.gov](http://data.gov) as per the CKAN API documentation. However, that file gives an HTTP 400 (Bad request) error.

Is there a way to search the datasets of all Federal government organization type?

Comment: Agreed, it looks like there is something wrong with the data.gov API. The same endpoint works fine at datahub: http://datahub.io/api/3/action/organization_list

Comment: These are both known, but unfortunately unresolved issues. You can track their status on github at https://github.com/GSA/data.gov/issues/294 and 
https://github.com/GSA/data.gov/issues/492. You can still filter by type using the web UI though, eg https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?organization_type=Federal+Government

Comment: @PhilipAshlock -- you should post this comment as an answer here and then later update when the Github issue is resolved, since this is the correct answer at this time.

Comment: @PhilipAshlock, I turned your comment into a community wiki answer. Please feel free to post your own answer any time – you deserve the reputation points :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Philip Ashlock for providing [the following answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4132/the-data-gov-organization-list-ckan-api-is-not-working#comment-5352):

> These are both known, but unfortunately unresolved issues. You can
>   track their status on github at
>   https://github.com/GSA/data.gov/issues/294 and 
>   https://github.com/GSA/data.gov/issues/492. You can still filter by
>   type using the web UI though, eg
>   https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?organization_type=Federal+Government